# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getLocation on channel lyokone/location)

Tags: flutter

E/flutter (13237): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getLocation on channel lyokone/location)

I am using Location and Place picker plugin

Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to create a platform view of unregistered type: plugins.flutter.io/google_maps

Comment: Try with `flutter clean` and then run

Comment: Tried same error

Comment: Flutter clean then restart IDE and try run.

Comment: No luck. Same issue

Comment: flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: 0.17.0-nullsafety

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  scoped_model: ^1.0.1
  rxdart: ^0.24.0
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  json_annotation: ^2.0.0
  flutter_html: ^1.0.2
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
  cached_network_image: ^2.3.3
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  country_code_picker: ^1.1.7
  url_launcher: ^5.4.11
  timeago: ^2.0.26
  flutter_rating_bar: ^3.2.0
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.18+1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  share: ^0.6.5+4

Comment: fluttertoast: ^3.1.3
  flutter_paystack: 1.0.4+1
  sign_in_with_apple: ^2.5.2
  image_picker: ^0.6.6+4
  flutter_webview_plugin: 0.3.10+1
  smooth_star_rating: ^1.1.1
  flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.1
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  fab_circular_menu: ^0.1.4
  google_fonts: ^0.3.5
  stripe_payment: ^1.0.7
  network_to_file_image: ^2.3.1
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  firebase_core: 0.5.0
  firebase_analytics: 6.0.0
  firebase_storage: 4.0.0
  cloud_firestore: 0.14.0+2
  photo_view: ^0.10.2
  intro_slider: ^2.3.1

Comment: #onesignal_flutter: ^2.6.1
  firebase_messaging: 7.0.0
  rounded_loading_button: ^1.0.14
  pin_code_fields: ^5.2.0
  gradient_input_border: ^1.0.0
  devicelocale: ^0.3.3
  lottie: ^0.7.0+1
  webview_cookie_manager: ^1.0.4
  place_picker: ^0.9.17
  location: ^2.3.5

Comment: Above plugins are used

Comment: `location: ^3.0.0`

Answer (score 8):

This error occurs when you add a package that hooks into the device like gps/camera/storage etc. without rebuilding the project.

To solve this, terminate the currently running project from your IDE, or if you're using `flutter run` in your terminal just press `q`.
Run `flutter clean` and then re-run the project again.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem when the proxy debugger (Proxyman or Charles) was started on my computer.

This worked for me:

1. Close proxy debugger
2. `flutter clean`
3. Restart IDE
4. Build app

Answer (score 2):

Try terminating your current running project and re-running. It will work. Refer [this](https://github.com/Lyokone/flutterlocation/issues/18) for more details.